# match and replace different values in same column from list

Tags: regex, perl, unix, awk

I want to replace the "0" digits from the second column with the second column of another file. For example, input 1, chr1 the second column is "0" and I would like to replace this with "754192" from the second column from the input 2 file and I would like to do this with the other "0" digits from the files so for chr2 in input 1 on the second column instead of "0" it would read "83616" from the input 2 file. Both input files are tab separated. I would really appreciate any perl/awk suggestions. Thank you.

input 1

```
chr1    0       121347754       0.004130250308662653
chr1    144009053       249250621       0.12551644444465637
chr2    0       90278124        -0.010306187905371189
chr2    95387134        243199373       -0.011985263787209988
chr3    0       91000000        -0.009726814925670624
chr3    93541117        198022430       -0.014836171641945839
chr4    0       49064792        -0.01315629668533802
chr4    52700771        141568601       0.014452865347266197
chr4    141568601       143871023       0.20834201574325562
chr5    0       46113638        -0.013212060555815697
chr5    49560859        68740653        0.004888067487627268
chr5    70744658        180915260       -0.011330894194543362
```

input 2

```
chr1    754192
chr2    83616
chr3    108226
chr4    90883
chr5    40975
chr6    209980
chr7    67820
chr8    193585
chr9    206255
chr10   126070
```

Output

```
chr1    754192       121347754       0.004130250308662653
chr1    144009053       249250621       0.12551644444465637
chr2    83616       90278124        -0.010306187905371189
chr2    95387134        243199373       -0.011985263787209988
chr3    108226       91000000        -0.009726814925670624
chr3    93541117        198022430       -0.014836171641945839
chr4    90883       49064792        -0.01315629668533802
chr4    52700771        141568601       0.014452865347266197
chr4    141568601       143871023       0.20834201574325562
chr5    40975       46113638        -0.013212060555815697
chr5    49560859        68740653        0.004888067487627268
chr5    70744658        180915260       -0.011330894194543362
```

Comment: yes tab separated data

Comment: You seem to have done it just fine! Please show what you have tried and need help with rather than asking for free code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this `awk`,

```
awk  'NR==FNR{ a[$1]=$2; next;} $2==0{ $2=a[$1]; }1' OFS="\t" input2 input1
```

Answer (score 2):

```
perl -MFile::Slurp -lape'
  BEGIN { %h = map split, read_file(pop); }
  $F[1] ||= $h{$F[0]};
  $_ = join "\t", @F;
' input1 input2
```

output

```
chr1   754192      121347754       0.004130250308662653
chr1    144009053       249250621       0.12551644444465637
chr2   83616      90278124        -0.010306187905371189
chr2    95387134        243199373       -0.011985263787209988
chr3   108226      91000000        -0.009726814925670624
chr3    93541117        198022430       -0.014836171641945839
chr4   90883      49064792        -0.01315629668533802
chr4    52700771        141568601       0.014452865347266197
chr4    141568601       143871023       0.20834201574325562
chr5   40975      46113638        -0.013212060555815697
chr5    49560859        68740653        0.004888067487627268
chr5    70744658        180915260       -0.011330894194543362
```

Comment: Did you mean `input2 input1`, using the OP's labels?

Comment: Why slurp when you don't have to?

Comment: @TLP what you're suggesting as alternative?

Comment: `my $x = shift; %h = map split, <>; push @ARGV, $x;` perhaps.

Comment: @TLP read_file() returns list of lines so it does pretty much same job.

Comment: @mpapec Ok, then how about that its not a core module?

Comment: @TLP in which perl is not core module? btw, is there nicer way for `s| \s\K 0 (?=\s) |`

Comment: I have perl v5.16 and it is not in corelist here. `corelist File::Slurp -> File::Slurp was not in CORE (or so I think)`.

Comment: I would not use a regex to check if it is `0`, I would use `eq` or `==`. Most likely `eq`, since the zero in this case seems to be a placeholder rather than a legitimate value.

Comment: You already have @F, so use it: `$F[1] = $h{$F[0]} if $F[1] == 0; $_ = join "\t", @F;`. You lose the original formatting, but you can always pipe the output through something like `column -t`

Comment: @glennjackman yes, or even `"@F"`, but delimiter might also be tab char which would be then converted into space.

Comment: `perldoc Some::Module` will work for any installed module with POD, core or not.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot you're missing the point which is, you don't have to manually install this particular module as it is already there on your system.

Comment: removing the module, we can: `perl -lane 'BEGIN {$,="\t"; %h=(); {local $/; open $f,"<",shift; %h=split /\s+/,<$f>}} @F[1] ||= $h{$F[0]}; print @F' input2 input1`

Comment: @mpapec I just installed perl-5.18.0. No File::Slurp. If it's not a core module, why would it already be on my system?

Comment: @mpapec It may be part of some distributions, I don't know, but its not in the core distribution, as far as I can tell. But tbh, I never saw the point of this module, when it can be replaced in its entirety with a few lines of code.

Comment: @glennjackman I would still avoid slurping, and as noted in other comments, I would prefer to use explicit variables when splitting to avoid one-off errors. Also, the use of `$,` over `join` is questionable. Your code should be `perl -lanwe 'BEGIN { open my $f, "<", shift or die $!; %h = map { chomp; my ($k,$v) = split /\t/; $k => $v;  } <$f>; $F[1] ||= $h{$F[0]; print join "\t", @F;' input2 input1`

Comment: @TLP, your BEGIN block is not closed. I relax my coding standards for one-liners. Not how I'd code a production script.

Comment: @glennjackman Then relax, don't add complexity. No point in splitting on `/\s+/` when you know the input is tab delimited, for example. Also, don't take my comments to heart, I'm just giving feedback, that's all.

Comment: I know, just professional back and forth. I used /\s+/ because I slurped the file and I wanted to split the whole contents into words, so really splitting on tabs and newlines (any whitespace).

Comment: @TLP indeed. It comes with strawberry, and installs by default on debian(/ubuntu?) as separate package. I like it for the same reason I like `List::Util`, even when I can do all these by hand.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot you're right, it depends which system you are running.

Comment: @glennjackman If you like `/\s+/` then you should check what the documents say about splitting on a literal space `' '`.

Comment: @mpapec Nevertheless, it can be replaced with 1-2 lines of code, so whats the point?

Comment: @TLP to be less cryptic, less `awk` like.

Comment: @mpapec No, I dont buy it. Slurp all you want, I'll be sticking with core Perl.

Answer (score 2):

This is one way to do it in Perl. The program expects the paths to the two files as parameters on the command line.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my ($file1, $file2) = @ARGV;
my $fh;

open $fh, '<', $file2 or die qq{Unable to open "$file2" for input: $!};
my %defaults = map {(split)[0,1]} <$fh>;

open $fh, '<', $file1 or die qq{Unable to open "$file1" for input: $!};

while (<$fh>) {
  my @fields = split;
  $fields[1] ||= $defaults{$fields[0]};
  print join("\t", @fields), "\n";
}
```

**output**

```
chr1  754192  121347754 0.004130250308662653
chr1  144009053 249250621 0.12551644444465637
chr2  83616 90278124  -0.010306187905371189
chr2  95387134  243199373 -0.011985263787209988
chr3  108226  91000000  -0.009726814925670624
chr3  93541117  198022430 -0.014836171641945839
chr4  90883 49064792  -0.01315629668533802
chr4  52700771  141568601 0.014452865347266197
chr4  141568601 143871023 0.20834201574325562
chr5  40975 46113638  -0.013212060555815697
chr5  49560859  68740653  0.004888067487627268
chr5  70744658  180915260 -0.011330894194543362
```

Comment: Your output doesn't match the OP's expected output. Compare the first `chr5` row, for example.

Answer (score 1):

Slightly more procedural version (without error checking).

```
use Modern::Perl;
use autodie;

# read input2 into map 
my %input2 = do { 
  open my $input2, '<', "input2";
  local $/ = undef;
  split( ' ', <$input2> );
};

open my $input1, '<', "input1";
while ( <$input1> ) {
  my ($id) = split( ' ' );
  if ( /^\w+\s+0\s/ ) {
    my $replace_with = $input2{$id};
    s/^(\w+\s+)0(\s)/$1$replace_with$2/;
  }

  print;
}
```

Comment: Why slurp the file when you don't have to? You only risk getting one-off errors if some value is missing, and don't gain anything. Also, use `' '` instead of `/\s+/` unless you wish to preserve leading whitespace. Also, `\b0\b` matches `0.123` -- you'll want to use `eq` or `==`.

Comment: hi, could you explain why i don't need to slurp the file? ( input2 has newlines ). Also not sure what you mean with == or eq. thanks for feedback.

Comment: You can read line by line and split each line, using for example `map`. Actually, you risk one-off errors anyway since `split` will strip trailing whitespace, unless you specifically assign a key value pair, i.e. `map { my ($k,$v) = split; $k => $v; } <$input2>`. Using `eq` will assure string equality, `==` numeric equality, and you would apply them to a value you get from splitting the string.

Answer (score 1):

One Liner in Perl:

```
$ perl -MFile::Slurp -lape 'BEGIN {$" = "\t"; %input = map { m/([^\s]+)\s*([^\s]+)/ } read_file("input_2")} $F[1] = $input{$F[0]} unless $F[1]' input_1
```

Comment: `[^\s]` better written `\S`

Comment: Fixed it for you. Also, with due respect, don't you think your answer is kind of a ripoff of answers already given?

Comment: I further shortened it to keep up with the Perl spirit. Your due respect is well taken as when I opened the question there were zero responses... I did not check/refresh the page before I posted my final answer which I tested before it worked.